# Hide matrix Gridlines SQL Server Reporting Services 2005

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, hide, gridlines

I am creating a report using SQL Server Reporting Services in Visual Studio 2005 (SSRS). I have placed a matrix in a list. The data and the matrix are working fine.

However I can't seem to find a way to hide the matrix grid lines at runtime. Also, I have set the visibility of the static 1st column and 1st row to false, but when the report is run, the space taken up by them is left empty. Is there a way to make the cells shift to the left (since the 1st static column has been set to invisible)?

Thanks in advance,
TM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK solved. Setting the BorderStyle to "None" will make the gridlines invisible.